# Backbone.js Router Routes case insensitive

Tags: backbone.js

Does anyone know how to make the Backbone routes case insensitive?

I.E.
http://localhost/Products
http://localhost/products

both trigger the products route

```
routes: {
    "products": "products"
},
```

---

### Update

Based on mu is too short's answer, here is the full Router. Thanks for your help

```
MainRouter = Backbone.Router.extend({
    routes: {
        "": "home",
        "products": "products"
    },

    initialize: function () {
        Backbone.history.start({ pushState: true });
    },

    home: function () {
        // just show the products!!
        this.products();
    },

    products: function () {

        // wire up the view.
        var ps = new ProductsView({ el: '#products', collection: myCollection });
        ps.render();

        // fetch the collection!!
        myCollection.fetch();
    },

    _routeToRegExp: function (route) {
        route = route.replace(this.escapeRegExp, "\\$&")
               .replace(this.namedParam, "([^\/]*)")
               .replace(this.splatParam, "(.*?)");

        return new RegExp('^' + route + '$', 'i'); // Just add the 'i'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could bind all your routes manually with [`Backbone.Router.route()`](http://documentcloud.github.com/backbone/#Router-route), that will accept the route as a string or a RegExp object:

```
Backbone.Router.route(/products/i, ...
```

Or you could replace this *private* method in `Backbone.Router` while *subclassing* (via `Backbone.Router.extend()`, thank you [Crescent Fresh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/45433/crescent-fresh)):

```
_routeToRegExp : function(route) {
  route = route.replace(escapeRegExp, "\\$&")
               .replace(namedParam, "([^\/]*)")
               .replace(splatParam, "(.*?)");
  return new RegExp('^' + route + '$');
}
```

with this one (you'll have to copy/expand the `escapeRegExp` `namedParam`, and `splatParam` regexes too):

```
_routeToRegExp : function(route) {
  route = route.replace(/[-[\]{}()+?.,\\^$|#\s]/g, "\\$&")
               .replace(/:\w+/g, "([^\/]*)")
               .replace(/\*\w+/g, "(.*?)");
  return new RegExp('^' + route + '$', 'i'); // Just add the 'i'
}
```

The routes in the `routes` object are added to the routing table using `Backbone.Router.route()` and that converts them to regexes using `_routeToRegExp`.

Here's a demo of the `_routeToRegExp` approach: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/MDSC5/

Comment: `Backbone.Router` is meant to be inherited (ie `Backbone.Router.extend({})`. One could simply override `_routeToRegExp` at that point.

Comment: @Crescent: Good point, thanks. I haven't used Backbone routing yet so I'm in unfamiliar territory here.

Comment: it seems that putting the 'i' breaks routes that look like "search/:query". Anyone else have this issue? I can't get those types of routes to work anymore with the above solution. If take out the "i" it works.

Comment: @KDV: Seems to work okay but you have to copy the `escapeRegExp`, `namedParam`, and `splatParam` regexes: http://jsfiddle.net/ambiguous/MDSC5/

Comment: @KDV: You could also try jbenet's approach, I'm not sure how portable the [`source`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/source) attribute is off the top of my head though but a quick browser check and perhaps a look at quirksmode.org should sort that out.

Answer (score 10):

The `optamd3` version of `Backbone.Router` does not seem to have the `escapeRegExp`, `namedParam`, and `splatParam` constants in `this`. In addition, entirely replacing a function is more likely to break in the future.

I solved it by just calling the overridden function, and using its `RegExp`:

```
var Router = Backbone.Router.extend({

  _routeToRegExp: function(route) {
    route = Backbone.Router.prototype._routeToRegExp.call(this, route);
    return new RegExp(route.source, 'i'); // Just add the 'i'
  },

  ...

});
```